# Rails controller testing: How to disable before_filter of controller while testing?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing, controller, before-filter

before_filter of controller expects user to be logged in. this is why test of controller fails(work fine if i remove user authentication call from before_filter). Is it possible if user authentication call can be disabled while testing ?

```
class Company::BranchController < ApplicationController
  before_filter **:require_user**, :only => [:show, :edit, :update, :new, :create, :index]

  def create
    @branch = Company::Branch.new(params[:branch])
    if @branch.save
      redirect_to :action => :index             
    else
      render :action => :new    
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

@Antiarchitect is correct, however, given the context of your problem, I think you should consider simulating having a user signed in vs. stubbing out the method checking.

There are ways to do this with the user/login packages out there.  For Devise, it provides a simple `sign_in @user` method; with Authlogic, you can do `UserSession.create @user`.  IMHO, I think your tests will be less brittle and less tied to implementation by doing it the latter way.

Answer (score 1):

May be you shouldn't disable before filter. I think you should just log in in a testing way:

```
 before(:each) do
   @current_user = Factory.create(:user)
   controller.stubs(:current_user).returns(@current_user)
 end
```

Comment: I am not using rspec, syntax u mentioned is rspec specific. is there way to use stubs without rspec.